# Is there a recommended workflow to automate producing PDF forms with embedded javascript?

Tags: pdf

We use a lot of PDF forms with embedded javascript. We generate PDFs from LibreOffice, then use Acrobat to add PDF controls and javascript. This isn't working well, because a change to the appearance of the form in LibreOffice then causes additional work in Acrobat to put the PDF controls back where they should be, and then re-do the javascript.

Is there a smart way to generate PDFs with the PDF controls built-in (text input boxes, check boxes, radio boxes, digital signature boxes), with all the javascript included in the source file?

For example, is there a tool that could convert an html form with embedded javascript into a PDF with the same javascript running in the PDF?

Answer (score 1):

I have a two step process.

First, create the PDF using Adobe InDesign. InDesign can add PDF interactive PDF fields to your document so that when exported, the fields are present.

The second step is to use a script to add scripted actions to each field like this...

```
this.getField("foo").setAction("MouseUp", "app.beep(0);");
```

See the [documentation](https://help.adobe.com/en_US/acrobat/acrobat_dc_sdk/2015/HTMLHelp/index.html#t=Acro12_MasterBook%2FJS_API_AcroJS%2FField_methods.htm%23TOC_setAction2bc-17&rhtocid=_6_1_8_31_2_16) for more actions.